# Link to virtual page in different html page: JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have 2 html pages in my mobile application index.html and individual.html. Index.html page includes many virtual pages. I have a button in individual.html page. I want to link it to a virtual page in the index.html.

Is it possible?

How exactly it can be done?

Please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create your linked button, in `individual.html`, like this: the following to your link :

```
<a data-role="button" rel="external" href="index.html#your_virtual_page">BUTTON</a>
```

Here is a working example of what could be your files `index.html` and `individual.html`:

**-** `index.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="home" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="content">
                HOME   
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- THE VIRTUAL PAGE THAT WE WANT TO ACCESS FROM individual.html -->
        <div id="p2" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="content">
                PAGE 2!!!
            </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

**-** `individual.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>          
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="home" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="content">
                <!-- YOUR LINK TO YOUR VIRTUAL PAGE IN index.html -->
                <a data-role="button" rel="external" href="./index.html#p2">TO PAGE 2</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="p1" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="content">
                P1
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps mate.